# Obtain 'Tags' of SharePoint item using the Client ObjectModel

Tags: development, client-object-model, tags

I would like to obtain the 'Tags' for each SharePoint (2010, 2013) list item (either a document in a library or an item in a list) using the Client Object Model.

I haven't found any API that let's me do that. Is it possible via the Client Object Model using C#?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? 2007, 2010 or 2013? The API vary a lot

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for both SharePoint 2010 and 2013

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You don't say if you mean C# or JavaScript. I'll assume JavaScript. Retrieve your item, and then:

```
var fieldValues = item.get_fieldValues();
var enumerator = fieldValues.taxonomyField.getEnumerator();
while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
    var term = enumerator.get_current();
    var termLabel = term.get_label();
    var termId = term.get_termGuid();
}
```

Note that if it's a single value taxonomy field, you don't need the enumerator. E.g.

```
var termLabel = fieldValues.taxonomyField.get_label();
```

Further note - you'll need to make sure your code loads the SP.Taxonomy.js file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have mentioned C#, although I will try and translate this JS code snippet to it's C# equivalent.

Comment: Is this part of the Client Object Model? I do not find any 'taxonomyField' member on the 'ListItem' type.ListItem.FieldValues is a Dictionary

Comment: 'taxonomyField' is just the internal name of your Taxonomy field. If you've called it 'thingy' then it would be 'fieldValue.thingy ...'. Similar code should work in C#